# Compatibility of ejb with jdk 1.8 and jboss eap 6.4

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I have an application deployed on WebSphere that uses jdk 1.5 and ejb 2.1 technologies.
I have to migrate it to Jboss eap 6.4 and JDK 1.8. Can I continue to use ebj 2.1 version? 
Thanks!

RB

Answer (score 0):

Using EJB 2.1 technologies in this version of JBoss EAP should be perfectly fine, **unless you're using CMP entity beans**, which would need to be migrated to JPA.

You can find a support matrix at [JBoss Enterprise Application Platform Supported Standards](https://access.redhat.com/articles/113373).

Further documentation can also be found at [EJB 2.X CHANGES](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.3/html/migration_guide/sect-ejb_2.x_changes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Direct queries are made, without using CRM objects. My doubt is also that ejb2.1 is compatible with JDK 8

Comment: EJB 2.1 is a specification. You only need to be concerned with whether or not your chosen implementation is Java 8 compatible. I have provided demos in the past of WildFly running EJB 2.1 beans on Java 8, so I don't think you will have any issues with JBoss EAP 6.4